# CSS: Rotate() on soundcloud iframe makes everything blurry

Tags: css, iframe, css-transforms

i tried to reproduce a problem, that occurs in a special combination: windows7 + chrome + soundclouds iframe widget - this problem does not occur on firefox, nor does it seem to exist on mac systems:

if i include soundcloud's iframe within a rotated div over another (back-)rotated div, everything is blurry after the iframe:

http://jsfiddle.net/aqbyhqr1/10/

css code:

```
 .outer {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(1deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(1deg);
}

.inner {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-1deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-1deg);
  /* this or backface-visibility: hidden; does not fix the problem */
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 51%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 51%;
  transform-origin: 50% 51%;
}
```

[image]

on what i currently work, it's even worse: [image]

i found some advise here to use `backface-visibility: hidden;` and/or `transform-origin: 50% 51%;`, but it did not change anything.